# Angular Animation using params receiving NG03000

Tags: angular

Hi i'm trying to create a angular component with parameters being passed in for the angular animation and I'm receiving a set of errors stating that the parameter is empty. I haven't been able to work out whether I can pass parameters this way (I couldn't locate the documentation for this).

The animation that I have is :

```
animations: [
trigger('openClose', [
  state(
    'open',
    style({
      opacity: 1,
      transform: 'scale(1)',
    })
  ),
  state(
    'closed',
    style({
      opacity: 0,
      transform: 'scale(0.8)',
    })
  ),
  transition('closed => open', [
    animate('{{ openTransitionDuration }} {{ openTransitionTimingFunction }}', style({ transform: 'scale(1)', opacity: 1 }))
  ]),
  transition('open => closed', [
    animate('{{ closeTransitionDuration }} {{ closeTransitionTimingFunction }}', style({ transform: 'scale(0.8)', opacity: 0 }))
  ]),
]),
trigger('prevNext', [
  state(
    'true',
    style({
      opacity: 1,
    })
  ),
  state(
    'false',
    style({
      opacity: 0,
    })
  ),
  transition('false => true', [
    animate('{{ leftTransitionDuration }} {{ leftTransitionTimingFunction }}', style({}))
  ]),
  transition('false => true', [
    animate('{{ rightTransitionDuration }} {{ rightTransitionTimingFunction }}', style({}))
  ]),
]),
trigger('imageAnimation', [
  transition('* => *', [
    style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'scale(0.8)' }),
    animate(
      '{{ openTransitionDuration }} {{ openTransitionTimingFunction }}',
      style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'scale(1)' })
    )
  ]),
]),
```

],

I'm passing the parameters as :

```
  @Input() openTransitionDuration: string = '4s';
  @Input() openTransitionTimingFunction: string = 'ease-in';
  @Input() openTransitionName: string = 'animate__fadeIn';
  
  @Input() closeTransitionDuration: string = '4s';
  @Input() closeTransitionTimingFunction: string = 'ease-out';
  @Input() closeTransitionName: string = 'animate__fadeOut';
  
  @Input() leftTransitionDuration: string = '4s';
  @Input() leftTransitionTimingFunction: string = 'ease-in';
  @Input() leftTransitionName: string = 'animate__fadeOutLeft';
  
  @Input() rightTransitionDuration: string = '4s';
  @Input() rightTransitionTimingFunction: string = 'ease-in';
  @Input() rightTransitionName: string = 'animate__fadeOutRight';
```

To test this out I'm just using the defaults as above when I declare the @Input statements.

in ngOnint I have console logged the variables and it showing the values. However, I'm receiving the following error :

> ERROR Error: NG03402: Unable to process animations due to the following failed trigger transitions
> NG03505: @imageAnimation has failed due to:
> NG03003: Please provide a value for the animation param openTransitionDuration

- NG03003: Please provide a value for the animation param openTransitionTimingFunction
- NG03000: The provided timing value " " is invalid.

As you can see above openTransitionDuration and openTransitionTimingFunction are both initialised. So I cannot work work out why the animation is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define an animation with params don't forget add in your trigger a params by defect. e.g. with a simple animation that use as params "width"

```
animations:[
    trigger('custom',[
      transition('*=>*', [
        style({ width: `{{width}}`  }), //<--this is a "param"
        animate('500ms ease-in', style({ width: `100%`  })),
      ],{params:{ width: "0"}}), //<---see that "params" is an object
                                 //that have a property "width"
    ])
  ]
```